# What state is a Cocoa app in when application(_:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:) is called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication, nsuseractivity

I'm going through hell trying to understand state in iOS apps :-(

I'm implementing Universal Links and the basics are working. However, I'm confused about the state of the app when this method is called in the `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

At the point this method is called... what has loaded?

I have a basic Storyboard app with a Nav Controller and two sub-controllers.

When this method is called (as a result of a universal link) at which state is my iOS app in? Have the controllers initiated?

I'm guessing if the app had already been started then it's at whatever state it was at before going into the background. Is that correct?

If the app hasn't loaded yet... then does this get called before my initial controller loads or what?

*disclaimer: I'm super new to iOS development and finding the state stuff a nightmare!